# Nested SQL cursor prints variable, but will not update

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, variables, cursor

I'm using nested cursors to update the first column on every table of my Database, to populate data for an online reporting program.

when testing my cursors using a print statement, everything runs fine. When I switch to the update command, I get an error saying variable @table must be defined. Why does the variable only work for a print, and how can I make this work correctly?

```
declare @table varchar (30)
declare @Column varchar (30)

DECLARE [TABLE] CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM 
postfixing.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' order 
by table_name
OPEN [TABLE]
FETCH FROM [TABLE] INTO @TABLE
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN
    DECLARE [COLUMN] CURSOR FOR SELECT Top 1 Column_name FROM 
postfixing.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME =@table order by 
column_name
    OPEN [COLUMN]
    FETCH FROM [COLUMN] INTO @COLUMN
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
        BEGIN
        PRINT @TABLE+'   '+@COLUMN
        --UPDATE @TABLE SET @COLUMN=@COLUMN
        FETCH FROM [COLUMN] INTO @COLUMN
        END
    DEALLOCATE [COLUMN]
    FETCH FROM [TABLE] INTO @TABLE
END
DEALLOCATE [TABLE]
```

Comment: Yeah.  You can't use variables like that.  You need to use dynamic SQL to replace identifiers in queries.

Comment: I apologize for any ignorance, but I've set my update statement as a variable using (I think) dynamic SQL. the issue I am now having is that it skips the first table, and now tries to update the second table with the columns for the first.  It looks like the outer cursor will loop through the first table, it just never steps in to update the column

Comment: Another case of _optimistic programming_. You want `UPDATE @TABLE SET @COLUMN=@COLUMN` to do what you _want_. Sometimes `@COLUMN` should be a variable and the value should be used or set. Other times the value should should be substituted into a statement, then the statement reparsed (perhaps recursively). So what would `SET @COLUMN=@COLUMN` mean? `SET [MyFirstColumn] = [MyFirstColumn]`? `SET [MyFirstColumn] = 'MyFirstColumn'`? Or simply `SET @COLUMN = @COLUMN`? [sp_executesql](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since you are only getting the first row you can eliminate the nested cursor and it should do what you want:

```
declare @table varchar (30)
declare @Column varchar (30)

DECLARE [TABLE] CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM 
postfixing.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' order 
by table_name
OPEN [TABLE]
FETCH FROM [TABLE] INTO @TABLE
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN

    SET @COLUMN = (SELECT Top 1 Column_name FROM 
postfixing.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME =@table order by 
column_name)

    PRINT @TABLE+'   '+@COLUMN
    --UPDATE @TABLE SET @COLUMN=@COLUMN

FETCH FROM [TABLE] INTO @TABLE
END
CLOSE [TABLE]
DEALLOCATE [TABLE]
```

Comment: A combination of this, and dynamic SQL to set the table name in the update statement resolved my issues. Thank you JM_ and Gordon Linoff for helping me with this. I still have a few questions on _why_ it was having these issues, but I can probably figure that out from here.